# How to load a defaut image from a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, handlebars.js

I have set a default image in a .hbs file on using

`<img src="{{source_image_number}}.png" alt={{source_image_number}} onerror="default_image.png">`.

,expexting that when there is a problem on loading the source image, the default image can be loaded instead of having a little broken image logo (specially for Chrome). Now I'm using another image as default which comes from a third-party class. It's like below in the css file:

`.icon-default: {
  content: '\e050';
  transform: translate(2px, 3.5px);
}`

I tried three solutions:

- create a class `<div class="default-image">` who contains the necessary information. Then use `onerror="this.display='none'"` and after that call class `default-image`. The problem of this solution is that when `{{source_image_number}}.png` is corrctly loaded the default image will be loaded too.
- use jquery in a .js file to deal with the onerror case. But while the jquery detects the problem of source image and reads the default one, the page has been fully loaded. As a result, there are on the same time the little broken image logo and the default image.
- use jquery to check whether the source image exists before loading the page. It ends by having a not-authentified-to-read-file-on-client-side issue (the error message is not exactly this but after having null error for several times I suppose that it's because of this).

The 4th solution I have on mind but not tested is to use a proxy to have the authentication and then do the check as mentioned in the 3rd solution but I hesitate whether there is a simpler way to do this.

What should I do to make this image as default?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put {{source_image_number}} instead of {source_image_number} ? If the syntax is related to handlebar the variables should be between the two {{ }} instead of one.

See syntax here http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Effectively I made a mistake while posting the question. The main problem is however loading an image in a class.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you could do but I think that I would try to do that: lazy load all images with a default one and use an intersection observer to load the true image (accessible with data-src) once the image become in sight. If you want more info on intersection observer you can have some here https://imagekit.io/blog/lazy-loading-images-complete-guide/